# How can I install libpython in windows?

Tags: windows-10, python

I have something installed that says:

`Failed dynamic library load, install the latest libpython3.x library`

I can't for the life of me figure out how to do this. Apparently I can use something called `pip install` but I have tried `pip install libpython` and `pip install libpython3.5` etc. and nothing works I just get:

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement libpython35 (from versions: )
> No matching distribution found for libpython35

Google is not producing anything useful either on how to do this.

My python version is 3.5.4 and I read somewhere I need to get the matching libpython

Any advice?